# Caddy not working in api-platfrom 2.6.4 distribution - panic: proto: file "pb.proto" is already registered

Tags: api-platform.com

When I try us api-platform version 2.6.4 I am not able to run it when i build adn strat containers and check logs caddy is not working i get an error like this. Any idea? Caddy version is 2.3.0

```
caddy_1     | panic: proto: file "pb.proto" is already registered
caddy_1     | See https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go/faq#namespace-conflict

tureality_caddy_1 exited with code 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Other people have reported having this bug and I had it too.

Fortunately, the bug as just been fixed by Dunglas itself. :)

https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/1881#issuecomment-822663193

The repair was done at the mercure level and not in the api platform source code itself so you can keep your current version.

You just have to docker-compose up and it will work.